# Some one next door( was playing/has played/had been playing / has been playing ) heavy metal music all night long.I didn't get a wink of sleep

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference between ( was playing and had been playing here ) what is the correct choise ?

Comment: 'Had been playing' takes the event further back in the past. "I was tired yesterday because someone next door _had been_ playing loud music all night."

Comment: The simple past, *played*, works. What makes you think “had been playing” might be right?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the context of the rest of the sentence. If you were telling a story, you would use `was playing` or `had been playing`

For example:

Person A: Why do you look so tired?

Person B: someone next door was playing/had been playing heavy metal music all night long.

In this situation, both those two options work, but `was playing` sounds better, and is overall the better choice.

If you were having a conversation with someone whilst the music was playing, then you could use one of the other two options.

Person B (on the phone to person A): I'm so tired
Person A: Why?
Person B: Someone next door has played/has been playing heavy metal music all night.

In this context, `has been playing` is the better way to say it.

Comment: I'd add that "Was playing" sounds like a one-off, eg it happened one night - while "Has been playing" implies it's been going on for a longer period, perhaps a few weeks.